# Text overflowing container with Zooming (CMD +)

Tags: css

Problem = Text overflowing container with Zooming (CMD +).

Before zooming =

[image]

After zooming =

[image]

The following solves it, but I am very reluctant to accept ViewPort units because of **their lack of full** support by all current Browsers, not to mention **the legacy Browsers**:

```
html {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 2.4vw;
}
```

Another much more serious problem with ViewPort units is that they obviously scale with window size and **I do not wish to do that**.

I wish:
**(1)** **nothing to happen** to the font-size with window resizing.
**(2)** ... but I do wish the font-size to decrease such that the above container overflow does not happen with zooming.
**(3)** avoid Javascript and CSS @media Queries if possible.

Here's the appropriate code:

HTML -

```
    <div id="roundedTextCorners" class="centerBlockContents">
        <div class="headerText">
MY VERY OWN GUARDIAN ANGEL!<p>

MY LOVE SONG FOREVER!!
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS -

```
#roundedTextCorners {
    border:           0.3125em #994c00 solid;
    border-radius:    0.625em;

    padding:          1.0em 1.0em 1.0em 1.0em;

    background-color: #994c00;
    color:            #fff;
}

.centerBlockContents {
    text-align: center;
}

.headerText {
    font-family: Georgia, Helvetica;
    font-size:   1.60em;   /* at the top level */
    color:       #fff;

    padding:     1.0em 1.0em 1.0em 1.0em;
}
```

Any ideas ??

Comment: So you don't want the user to be able to zoom and you don't want the font-size to depend on the window size. Hm. I was going to suggest <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />, but that's only fore mobile. Let me think.

Comment: I already have the meta tag on top which works for mobile. My concern is for desktop. I can accept zooming even there, but eventually with enough zooming, there is a point when the overflow happens because of the resulting super big font-size. With the super big size and word-break just one letter appears which by itself overflows. BTW overflow:hidden doesn’t work. Obviously the user will definitely back off such a ridiculous zoom - so I guess this is just a academic pursuit. @media works, but I don’t like these calls.

Comment: Wait a minute, I just remembered. You asked this question before, didn't you? And I posted [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/vmvqsaL1/2/) in response, to see how you liked it.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, thanks Mr. Lister, for sticking with me on this challenge.

I finally I decided on a "solution" I was happy with. Inevitably, I decided a max-width had to go somewhere, either in the `<body>` or in `@media`. I chose `@media` because I concluded I despised horizontal scroll bars more than the jerkiness inherent to `@media`.